# How to autowire spring-data repository, getting 'No qualifying bean'

Tags: spring-data

I have a spring boot application where I want to use spring-data. However, the application fails to autowire the repository.

When I start the application it fails with:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in xxx.MyBean required a bean of type 'xxx.MyRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'xxx.MyRepository' in your configuration.

Error creating bean with name [...]
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'xxx.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The repository is:

```
interface MyRepository : CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {}
```

and the Entity:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
data class MyEntity(
    @Id
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val name: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this setup is that the entity is misconfigured.

**Add the `@Table` annotation to the entity class so that spring-data has the necessary information.**

Although the application startup error complains about a missing bean, this is the actual problem. By missing the table annotation spring-data does not recognize that it needs to wire the Repository interface, causing the error above.

```
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id

@Table("my_entity")
data class MyEntity(
    @Id
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val name: String
)
```